# Flutter webrtc not working properly in release mode

Tags: flutter, webrtc

I am using WebRTC for video conference within my flutter app.
The app works as expected in debug mode. I am able to establish the connection and the video from both ends is visible without any issues.
However, when I build an apk and test it on real devices, video conferencing fails. Video from both devices is not showing up on the screen. It is only a white screen with no videos where there should be 2 videos.

Here's the code I am referring to: https://github.com/md-weber/webrtc_tutorial

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have learnt is WebRTC is not really a production ready solution. One still needs to setup STUN/TURN server as discussed here - https://github.com/flutter-webrtc/flutter-webrtc-server/issues/30

If one is excited to explore in future, they can refer to -
https://meetrix.io/blog/webrtc/coturn/installation.html
https://medium.com/av-transcode/what-is-webrtc-and-how-to-setup-stun-turn-server-for-webrtc-communication-63314728b9d0

I do not have the time or energy to spend on this now, but will surely be back when we have a bigger team. For now I am going to use on of the readymade solutions in the market.

Answer (score 0):

When you compile the release apk, you need to add the following operations,

1-Edit /android/app/build.gradle

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        minifyEnabled true
        useProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

2-And create new file /android/app/proguard-rules.pro

```
 ## Flutter wrapper
-keep class io.flutter.app.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugin.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.util.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.view.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugins.**  { *; }
-dontwarn io.flutter.embedding.**

## Flutter WebRTC
-keep class com.cloudwebrtc.webrtc.** { *; }
-keep class org.webrtc.** { *; }
```

refer to [https://flutter-webrtc.org/docs/flutter-webrtc/get-stared#important-reminder][1]